# Selection within table for new column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the table `pricedata` (see attached file). I want to add two extra columns to this table (`MinPrice of Competitor` and `CompetitorID of MinPrice`). I wrote a code to get the column `MinPrice of Competitor`, BUT I have no idea how to get second column, any help ????

Code:

```
select a.ValuationDate, a.shop, a.Itemcode, a.OwnPrice,
       a.[sales price competitor], a.[competitor ID], b.MinPrice
from [PriceTable] a
  inner join
      (select ValuationDate, Shop, ItemCode,
              min([sales price competitor]) as MinPrice
       FROM [PriceTable]
       group by ValuationDate, Shop, ItemCode) b
    on  a.ValuationDate = b.ValuationDate
    and a.Shop = b.Shop
    and a.ItemCode = b.ItemCode
```

Actual Table:

[image: Actual Table]

Required Table:

[image: Required Table]

Comment: Look here for how to ask a good question.Think your self as another person who is having no clue about what you are asking and what can you do to get max help:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Reduce the sample data, and also show us the expected result!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. Hope this helps.

```
select 
    a.ValuationDate, 
    a.shop
    a.Itemcode, 
    a.OwnPrice, 
    a.[sales price competitor],
    a.[competitor ID],  
    b.MinPrice ,
    MINCOMPID.[competitor ID] AS 'CompetitorID of MinPrice'
from [PriceTable] a
inner join 
(
select ValuationDate, Shop, ItemCode, min([sales price competitor]) as MinPrice   FROM [PriceTable]
group by ValuationDate, Shop, ItemCode
) b
on a.ValuationDate=b.ValuationDate and a.Shop=b.Shop and a.ItemCode=b.ItemCode
INNER JOIN [PriceTable] AS MINCOMPID
ON MINCOMPID.ValuationDate=b.ValuationDate and MINCOMPID.Shop=b.Shop and MINCOMPID.ItemCode=b.ItemCode AND MINCOMPID.[sales price competitor]=b.MinPrice
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at (not tested). A common way to get the row with min/max value is SELECT TOP(1)  .. ORDER BY .. DESC/ASC

```
select a.ValuationDate, a.shop, a.Itemcode, a.OwnPrice,
       a.[sales price competitor], a.[competitor ID], 
       c.MinPrice, c.[competitor ID]
from [PriceTable] a
cross apply
   (SELECT TOP(1) b.[competitor ID]
              b.[sales price competitor] as MinPrice
    FROM [PriceTable] b     
    WHERE a.ValuationDate = b.ValuationDate
    and a.Shop = b.Shop
    and a.ItemCode = b.ItemCode  
    ORDER BY b.[sales price competitor] DESC) c
```